# How to display json data from api in tabular form?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I am new to angular.I am trying to **consume the data from api** https://api.covid19india.org/travel_history.json. How to print the data from above api json data in tabular form? Is there any changes required? When the angular application is served the **travel_history** is to be in tabular form.

Here is the `Component.ts`

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { coronaApi } from "../service/service";
import { HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
@Component({
selector:'corona',
templateUrl:'./component.html'
})
export class CoronaComponent{
public result:Array<any>;
constructor(public service:coronaApi){}
ngOnInit(){
this.service.getData().subscribe((posRes)=>{
this.result=(posRes);
},(errRes:HttpErrorResponse)=>{
console.log(errRes)
})
}
}
```

Here is the `component.html`.

```
<table border="2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th colspan="11"> Travel History </th>
            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>_CN6CA</th>
            <th>Accuracy Location</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Datasource</th>
            <th>Latlong</th>
            <th>Mode of Travel</th>
            <th>Pid</th>
            <th>Place Name</th>
            <th>Time From</th>
            <th>Time to</th>
            <th>Type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let x of result";*ngFor = " let y of x ">
            <td>{{y._cn6ca}}</td>
            <td>{{y.accuracylocation}}</td>
            <td>{{y.address}}</td>
            <td>{{y.datasource}}</td>
            <td>{{y.latlong}}</td>
            <td>{{y.modeoftravel}}</td>
            <td>{{y.pid}}</td>
            <td>{{y.placename}}</td>
            <td>{{y.timefrom}}</td>
            <td>{{y.timeto}}</td>
            <td>{{y.type}}</td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add your ts file as code and not as image

Comment: take account thet you need equal `this.result=posRes.travel_history`, this result must be the **array**, futhermore, as Cristhian say remove the let y of x, use simply `<tr *ngFor="let y of result">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your ts file you add a boolean and display the data after the response. You don't need second loop just set
**this.result = response.travel_history;**

**ts**

```
isDataLoaded: boolean = false;
public result;

ngOnInit(){
   this.service.getData().subscribe(response => {
   this.result = response.travel_history;
   this.isDataLoaded = true;
   }); 
 }
```

**html**

```
<tbody *ngIf="isDataLoaded">
    <tr *ngFor="let x of result">
        <td>{{x._cn6ca}}</td>
        <td>{{x.accuracylocation}}</td>
        <td>{{x.address}}</td>
        <td>{{x.datasource}}</td>
        <td>{{x.latlong}}</td>
        <td>{{x.modeoftravel}}</td>
        <td>{{x.pid}}</td>
        <td>{{x.placename}}</td>
        <td>{{x.timefrom}}</td>
        <td>{{x.timeto}}</td>
        <td>{{x.type}}</td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: @ManojKumar Great! Please if you can set it as answer

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will work. While you are subscribing to `getData()` function you should use second loop.

```
this.result = response.travel_history;
```

Here are the `component.ts`

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { coronaApi } from "../service/service";
import { HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
@Component({
selector:'corona',
templateUrl:'./component.html'
})
export class CoronaComponent{
public result:Array<any>;
constructor(public service:coronaApi){}
ngOnInit(){
this.service.getData().subscribe((posRes)=>{
this.result=posRes.travel_history;
},(errRes:HttpErrorResponse)=>{
console.log(errRes)
})
}
}
```

Here are `component.html`

```
<tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let y of result">
            <td>{{y._cn6ca}}</td>
            <td>{{y.accuracylocation}}</td>
            <td>{{y.address}}</td>
            <td>{{y.datasource}}</td>
            <td>{{y.latlong}}</td>
            <td>{{y.modeoftravel}}</td>
            <td>{{y.pid}}</td>
            <td>{{y.placename}}</td>
            <td>{{y.timefrom}}</td>
            <td>{{y.timeto}}</td>
            <td>{{y.type}}</td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
```